# Interpolate XYZ data to give accurate raster output

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation

I have XYZ Bathymetry Data which I would like to turn into a raster using the minimum value or shoal biased in QGIS.

I've tried using the `rasterize - vector to raster` function, but I can't change how the raster is created.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

These interpolation methods are not includeded/implemented in QGIS. use another programm for interpolation and import the raster in QGIS.